# How to go back to a snapshot after moving elsewhere in history?

Tags: darktable

I was editing my photo in DarkTable.

I took a snapshot and then went back in the history and tried to use a different approach to editing my photo.

My new approach looked worse than the snapshot of my previous edits.

How can I now go back to the snapshot that I took and keep editing from there?

Kinda weird the manual doesn't even mention it.

Comment: Which application?

Comment: Darktable, as per the question tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snapshot only saves the appearance of the image. It does not save the history stack that created it. A useful way of thinking about snapshots is they are more like thumbnails than anything else...probably why they are called “snapshots”.

For me, the easiest way to save the history stack before major changes is by creating a duplicate (ctrl-d) before the edits. The alternatives are creating/saving a style or making one or more presets in specific modules. There are times when those make a better workflow, but those times are rare.

The snapshot module allows comparing the *rendered* results of a past history stack to the current one. But it only stores the rendered result. This makes the comparison quick and computationally easy. And that’s usually the better for users because there are options when the user wants something else.

Comment: The snapshots are named by their position in the history stack. Technically, you can revert your image to the state it was in when taking the snapshot by going back to the particular point in the history stack (they're conveniently numbered).

Comment: @edison23 the question is about going “forward” to where the snapshot was made after reverting the history stack to a point before the snapshot and making edits that are unsatisfactory.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't read carefully enough. In that case, I agree with your suggestion to create a duplicate and test the edits there.